# Wishlist Add/Remove

Tags: magento-1.9, wishlist

In product page, I want to implement two buttons for ADD and Remove wishlist. 
In my product page, I have Customer ID and Product ID. 
I tried this `Mage::getModel('wishlist/item')->load($id)->delete();` for remove wishlist link action.

Is it possible to implement **Add to wishlist** link and **Remove from wishlist** link in the product page.

Look I'm new in Magento.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add to Wishlist:

```
<a href="<?php echo $this->helper('wishlist')->getAddUrl($_product) ?>" class="link-wishlist"><?php echo $this->__('Add to Wishlist') ?></a>
```

Remove:

```
<?php 
$_wishlistItem = Mage::getModel('wishlist/item')->loadByProductWishlist(
     $this->helper('wishlist')->getWishlist()->getId(),
     $_product->getId(),
     $_product->getStoreId()
);
$_wishlistRemoveUrl = $this->helper('wishlist')->getRemoveUrl($_wishlistItem); ?>
<a href="<?php echo $_wishlistRemoveUrl ?>" class="link-wishlistz"><?php echo $this->__('Remove from Wishlist') ?></a>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But the remove wishlist is not working. When I click on the remove link it will redirect to the page itself and nothing happens.

Comment: Updated my answer and tested it, it should be working now